# how should i solve this fration of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

hi everybody i have a question i can't solve 
$$\left|\frac{Z-W}{1-\overline ZW}\right|=1$$

the question says the above is true ,use it and prove $|Z|=1$ or $|W|=1$

i have tried putting $Z = x +iy$ and $W= a +ib$  and done some math works but it doesnt get to what question wants

thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|a+b|^{2}=|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}+2\Re \overset {-} a b$ for any two complex numbers $a$ and $b$. Since $|Z-W|^{2}=|1-\overset {-} Z W|^{2}$ we get $(1-|Z|^{2})(1-|W|^{2})=0$ after some simplifications. Hence $|Z|=1$ or $|W|=1$.

Comment: i can't believe how ease that was thank you man

Comment: but is this true? |Z-W|^2 = |Z|^2 + |W|^2 - 2*|Z|*|W| ???

Comment: No. $|Z-W|^{2}=|Z|^{2}+|W|^{2}-2 \Re \overset {-} Z W$.

Comment: yeah just found the formula in the book too thanks!